# MySQL show code if table > 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table called "cat_id".

My website is coded to display a list of sentences per page. But i also want these divs that show the sentences on the page to display the category id that they are.

So the categories only start above the number 0 in my database. So how would i make an if statment that says and put it in these divs where the content is displayed that if the "cat_id" is above 0 that it displays this code.

```
<div class="meta">
<small class="float-left gray">
Your Category: <a href="<?=$u?>categories/<?=$cat_record['cat_id']?>/<?=$page_no?>"><?=stripslashes($cat_record['cat_id'])?></a>
</small>
</div>
```

Comment: So how would i display that code if the number in that table is above 0? Not having much success im new to MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assume this code is lifted from within the query body, if so, you can just wrap an if statement around it

```
<?php if ($cat_record['cat_id'] > 0): ?>
    <div class="meta">
    <small class="float-left gray">
    Your Category: <a href="<?=$u?>categories/<?=$cat_record['cat_id']?>/<?=$page_no?>"><?=stripslashes($cat_record['cat_id'])?></a>
    </small>
    </div>   
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I like this but for some reason they all return one category maybe i chose the wrong '$cat_record['cat_id']' how would i get a category from one whole mysql entry in a database?

Comment: You'll need to share a bit more code of what query you are running and how you are parsing it to fully answer it

Comment: Figured it out i was using the wrong $cat_record it had to be something else but it works!!! Thanks! :D

Comment: Kinda get the idea behind tables now i think

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your returned value from `$cat_record['cat_id']` is being interpreted as a string so can't be used for integer comparisons in an if statement.

Try converting to an integer and comparing that.

```
$cat_int = intval($cat_record['cat_id']);
if($cat_int>0)
{
     //Code here
}
```

Comment: `$cat_record['cat_id']` would be type-juggled in the conditional. No need to pass it to `intval` first, i.e., `"1" > 0` returns true;

Answer (score 0):

You can of course get all entries from your database and use a condition in your php code to display only the ones with cat_id>0, but I think it is much cleaner to retrieve only those from the database that you need in the first place using a WHERE clause in your SQL statement.

Try the following:

```
<?php
    //Get results above 0
    $query="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE cat_id>0";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $cat_records=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) $cat_records[]=$row;

    //Loop through results to display the div
    foreach($cat_records as $cat_record){
        echo '<div class="meta"><small class="float-left gray">Your Category: <a href="'.$u.'categories/'.$cat_record['cat_id'].'/'.$page_no.'">'.stripslashes($cat_record['cat_id']).'</a></small></div>';
    }
?>
```